# What type is SOAP maps to enumerations?

Tags: enums, nusoap

A field in database at server-side is defined as ENUM. A row of database is returned via a web service including the field. I have to define a type for the returned result. In PHP, I use NuSoap for this purpose. I use addComplexType function. How this function should be called? With what parameters? How the definition of the type should be? I prefer the produced code with Visual Studio, after I update the web references, include an enumeration for the field instead of a simple string or integer. I hope I could explain what I need good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the method for creating a new type of enum:

```
$server->wsdl->addSimpleType('ServerStatus', 'xsd:string', 'SimpleType', 'struct',‎
‎    array(‎
‎        'Off',‎
‎        'Stopped',‎
‎        'Running'‎
‎    ));‎
```

Then, in Server structure the following line defines the server's status:

```
'Status' => array('name' => 'Status', 'type'=> 'tns:ServerStatus')
```

When web references are updated at client side, ServerStatus is translated to enum.